# Row size not declared in 2d array in C

Tags: c

In some programs involving 2d array, written in C, I noted that row size is not mentioned and the compiler is also not throwing any error regarding this. But when I tried this by mentioning the row size but not the column size, the compiler throws an error.

Eg:

```
int arr[][5]; // correct

int arr[5][]; //compiler throws error
```

What's the reason?

Comment: https://www.learn-c.org/en/Multidimensional_Arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can define a 2-D array in C as:

```
A [][n];
```

*where n is some constant*

We must include the number of columns in the array because this specifies the size of each row. The two dimensional array can be viewed as an array of rows.Once the compiler knows the size of a row in the array (which is defined by the value in the second square bracket, n here), it is able to correctly determine the beginning of each row.
In other words,it is needed to compute the relative offset of the item you're actually accessing.

**We have offset = (row*colwidth + col)**

The offsets are computed by the compiler using the size of the row, which happens to be the number/count of the columns.

Comment: In C, a *definition* reserves memory for an object, and the complete size must be known. You cannot define an array with a missing dimension. You can *declare* an array with a missing first dimension. If it is used, it must be defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> **6.7.6.2 Array declarators**
> **Constraints**
> 1 In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit
> an expression or **`*`**. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
> expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
> have a value greater than zero. ***The element type shall not be an incomplete or function
> type.*** The optional type qualifiers and the keyword **`static`** shall appear only in a
> declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost
> array type derivation.
> ...
> **Semantics**
> ...
> 4 If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type...

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.  Given an array declaration

```
T a[];
```

the type of `a` is *incomplete* - it's "unknown size array of `T`".  However, per the constraint above, `T` itself *must* be a complete type.  If `T` is an array type, its size must be known, *a la* `R [N]`:

```
R a[][N]; // a is an unknown-size array of N-element arrays of R
```

This is why the compiler accepts

```
int arr[][5];
```

since, while we don't yet know how many elements will be in `arr`, we know how big each of those elements will be (`5 * sizeof (int)`).  Note that `arr` *must* be given a size before it can actually be used.  The converse,

```
int arr[5][];
```

says that `arr` is a 5-element array of *unknown*-size arrays of `int`.  We know how many elements we need, but we don't know how big those elements are going to be.

Now, *why* does C make this restriction?  I can't provide an authoritative answer for that, but I suspect it has to do with the relationship between array and pointer operations in C.  Remember that the expression `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - that is, take the address `a` and offset `i` *elements* (**not bytes!!**) from that address and dereference the result.  That only works if the size of the element type is known.

It *should* be possible to model an array of N elements of unknown size, but I suspect that such a model is cumbersome *enough* that it's more trouble to implement than it's worth.

Comment: *"It should be possible to model an array of N elements of unknown size"*, in C this is quite possible by using typedef of VLA.